# Converting multiple .xls format files to .xlsx format

Tags: linux, conversion, spreadsheet

I am new to Linux. I know that there are ways to convert between file formats in Linux through the terminal. But is there any way I achieve the following?

I have 3 folders, inside those folders, there are 15 more folders. Each of those folders has 12 files in .xls format, and some other .R files and pdf files. Is there a way to create an exact duplicate of these 3 folders, inside which all the .xls are converted to .xlsx format?

If the following seems too unsubstantial, what is the way to just convert all the .xls files in one folder into .xlsx file format? Then I can replicate the aforesaid.

note: I don't have LibreOffice, I use WPS. If the following requires LibreOffice I can install it if necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will require `libreoffice`

From this Stack Overflow question [Unix command to convert xls file into xlsx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531212/unix-command-to-convert-xls-file-into-xlsx-file) :

```bash
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx my.xls --headless
```

Note that the `--convert-to` option implies the `--headless` option (it did not in Libreoffice version 4.2.3 when the SO answer above was written in 2014, but has done so since **at least** Libreoffice 6 in 2018, and probably much longer than that). It doesn't hurt to add it to the command line, but it isn't required.

Then you can integrate it into a `find` command :

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.xls" -exec libreoffice --convert-to xlsx {} \;
```

This command will look for files, in the current directory, with a name ending with `.xls` and execute the command replacing `{}` by the filename.

[man libreoffice](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/libreoffice.1.html) states :

> ```
> --convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir output_dir] file...
> ```
>
> Batch  converts  files.   If  `--outdir`  is  not  specified then the current working directory is used as the output directory for the converted files.  It implies `--headless`
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>  --convert-to pdf *.doc
> ```
>
> Converts all .doc files to PDFs.
>
> ```
>  --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/user *.doc
> ```
>
> Converts all .doc files to PDFs using the settings in the Writer PDF export  dialog and saving them in /home/user.

From @cas in the comments,

> libreoffice can take multiple filename arguments (the examples from the man page show this) so it would be faster to run as find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec libreoffice --convert-to xlsx {} + - only needing to run libreoffice once instead of once per file

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec libreoffice --convert-to xlsx {} +
```

Comment: +1. BTW, libreoffice can take multiple filename arguments (the examples from the man page show this) so it would be faster to run as `find . -type f -name '*.xls' -exec libreoffice --convert-to xlsx {} +` - only needing to run libreoffice once instead of once per file

Answer (score 0):

Minor modification to the answer by @Nicolas to make it work for MacOS: you have to point to the libreoffice binary since the command "libreoffice" may not be defined for the shell. In my case, it was:

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.xls" -exec /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --convert-to xlsx {} \;
```